# Check if Firebase event executed successfully

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm using the *`FirebaseAnalytics`* to track usage statistics for my `application`. I have included the following libraries:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```

I'm logging the following way:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString( "test_argument", "test_value" );
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent( "eventTest", params );
```

The `logging` works fine and is showing up on the account, but the problem is I can't find a single example for android how to check if the request was `executed` successfully.

How can I check the status of logEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable verbose logging to monitor logging of events by the SDK to help verify that events are being logged properly. This includes both automatically and manually logged events.

**Also**

You can view aggregated statistics about your events in the Firebase console dashboards. These dashboards update periodically throughout the day. For immediate testing, use the logcat output as described in the previous section.

You can access this data in the Firebase console as follows:

In the Firebase console, open your project.
Select Analytics from the menu to view the Analytics reporting dashboard.
The Events tab shows the event reports that are automatically created for each distinct type of event logged by your app. Read more about the Analytics reporting dashboard in the Firebase Help Center.

Firebase handles the logging event on its own.If there is no internet at the time the event happened firebase would itself take care of it and log the event when internet get connected.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Before I accept, even though Firebase handles the events automatically (if there's no internet), is there a way to detect if the event failed at that moment (problematically)?

Comment: There is no scenario that the event would fail and if it got failed suppose for a X reason then Firebase would retry it and send it again.
So there is no mechanism to test the fail log.